# iAd Freezes App iPhone 5[s][c]

Tags: sprite-kit, iad, iphone-5

My team and I just finished our very first app, and we ran into a problem with iAd.
We're still using the Apple developer ads; but if we tap on the Ad, then close out of the ad and click on a node it crashes the app, it seems to only be happening on the iPhone 5[s][c] though, does anyone know what could be causing this?

EDIT: We're using SpriteKit.

Comment: How do I post the code for iAd?  It's just the default code used to get it started up.  We actually managed to fix this issue by moving the ad to the top of the screen, but that doesn't make since...

Comment: Same here, but happens with the ad at the top.