# iAds and SpriteKit: SKScene Freeze on fullscreen exit on device only

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

My issue is similar to this one here
[iAd freezes game's scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943829/iad-freezes-games-scene?answertab=active#tab-top), but I feel the issue hasn't been resolved.

I have an iAd in it's own view overlayed over an SKScene so that it doesn't affect the SKScene sizing. The banner functions correctly but on fullscreen exit the SKScene is frozen. App is still receiving touch inputs, verified via NSLogs. If I click the banner again though and exit fullscreen the second time around the SKScene is no longer frozen. Why?

It's important to say that this happens only when testing on a device (iPhone5). On the simulator, there are no issues. Has anyone figured out this conundrum?

Issue is similar to this post [iAD View Freezes On Ad Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595148/iad-view-freezes-on-ad-close) but the solution: 'Remove self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES' doesn't work for me.
While I've tried creating it programatically also, I've implemented the iAd via storyboard, and this is not relevant.

The issue is also here [iAd Freezes App iPhone 5[s][c]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585840/iad-freezes-app-iphone-5sc) but the solution is short of superstition and still remains a mystery.

--

The alternative solution to implement an iAd with SpriteKit via self.canDisplayBannerAds and originalContentView works and functions correctly but produces a sizing/scaling issue as it shares the view with the SKScene ([Spritekit iAds messing with scene size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873420/spritekit-iads-messing-with-scene-size)) which I'd rather avoid, but am willing to use smoke and mirrors to hide the ugly resizing animation/effect as a last resort.

--

If anyone knows the best way to implement an iAd with SpriteKit without sizing issues or freezing issues on device please let me know.

Comment: did you add the iAD by dragging one from the object library?  I did, and did not use self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES.  There are some other things you need to do as well, but I get no freezing of my App no matter how many times I click on the Ads. And the App is on the store getting ads and everything.  Let me know if I can help you out.

Comment: Yeah, dragged it from the object library also and removed self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES. What are the other things I need to do? It still freezes on the device, but unfreezes on 2nd time around.

Comment: The other things I was talking about are.. Import iAd into the view controller that holds the SKScene, and make it an ADBannerViewDelegate so you can implement the following. bannerViewDidLoadAd, bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError, bannerViewActionSHouldBegin, and bannerViewActionDidFinish. Also, make the ADBanneView a property.

Comment: I'm having this same issue but presenting a modal viewcontroller. The skscene freezes and unfreezes the second time i return from the modal. Any ideas?

Comment: um, OP, have you figured this one out? I am having the exact same symptoms and no one has solved it for me yet :(